# Why file permissions work in unexpected manner? And what makes it possible

Tags: file-permissions, emulators

My app doesn't have [storage permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#STORAGE), yet I can read/write files in /data/user/0/com.myapp/files .

When on emulator connected as root I can push a file to this directory, but then the app cannot read it.

After I chown it to my app's uid:gid it still cannot read/write to it.

If I do `run-as com.myapp touch newfile` and then as root `cat pushedfile >> newfile`, then my app can read `newfile`.

What kind of dark magic is that? Why regular unix file permissions don't seem to work, and what mechanism prevents the app to read `pushedfile` even after it was `chown`ed?

I tried reading [the docs™](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#arch) but they don't seem to clarify anything.

Comment: What you experience seems to be SELinux/SEAndroid. Files outside of the appropriate SELinux context are not accessible in a given context. Your app is in a different context than your root user.

Comment: @GiantTree you're right. This is it.